# how to pass a list of values in struct in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, struct

I know how to pass a list of values in arrays

```
   int[] unit = new int[] {1,-3,3,4};
        string[] letter_grade = new string[] {"a+","B","c","W"};
        double totalGPA;
        GPA get = new GPA();
        get.getgpa(unit, letter_grade ,out totalGPA);
```

but i wanted to know how to pass it using structs i can send single value but not getting how to send list of values

```
         double totalGPA;
        GPA get = new GPA();
        GPAList[] Val = new GPAList[1];
        Val[0].grade ="d";
        Val[0].unitgrade = 4;
        get.getgpa(Val[0], out totalGPA);
```

Comment: I'm not understanding what your question is here.  I think what you're asking is how you would create an array of structures and pass that array, or possibly a linked list of structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just pass the struct array `Val` to getgpa:

```
get.getgpa(Val, out totalGPA);
```

Then `getgpa` should accept a array of GPA structs:

```
void getgpa(GPA[] gpas, out double totalGPA)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood your question, you want to pass a collection of values using struct.

A struct is not meant for storing collections, for collections we've arrays, arraylist, hashtable etc in c#.

The purpose of a struct is to represent a complete information into a single datatype. Structures are simply lightweight classes, they are no way used for collections.

If you want to use structures for storing collection of values, then again you'll have to make array of structures.

If you want to pass array of a structure, then in the formal parameter list, you should expect array of that structure itself, for eg.

```
**get.getgpa(Val, out totalGPA);**
```

for above code to work, the signature of getgpa function should be:

```
**getgpa(GPA[] arr,out double totalGPA)**
```

Hope this helps.